# Why is math.Pow performance worse than bitshifting?

Tags: go, compiler-optimization, bit-shift

When solving [this exercise](https://exercism.io/my/tracks/go#exercise-grains) on Exercism website, I have used the standard math.Pow package function to get the raising powers of two.

```
return uint64(math.Pow(2, float64(n-1)))
```

After checking the community solutions, I found a solution using bit shifting to achieve the same thing:

```
return uint64(1 << uint(n-1)), nil
```

What surprised me is that there is a big performance difference between the two:
[bit-shifting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvhCY.png)
[math-pow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6tdL.png)

I thought that the Go compiler would recognize that math.Pow uses a constant 2 as the base and just utilize bit shifting on its own, without me explicitly doing it so. The only other difference I can see is the conversion of the float64 and that math.Pow is operating on floats and not on integers.

Why doesn't the compiler optimize the power operation to achieve performance similar to bit shifting?

Comment: Note that optimizing `math.Pow` is only possible if the compiler can prove that `n` is between 1 and 64.

Comment: Note that `uint64(1) << (n-1)` is a better version of `uint64(1 << uint(n-1))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that `uint64(1) << (n-1)` is a better version of the expression `uint64(1 << uint(n-1))` that appears in your question. The expression `1<<n` is an `int`, so valid shift values are between 0 and either 30 or 62 depending on the size of int. `uint64(1) << n` allows `n` between 0 and 63.

In general, the optimization you suggest is incorrect. The compiler would have to be able to deduce that `n` is within a particular range.

See this example [(on playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/UJNk6VhdUer)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    n := 65
    fmt.Println(uint64(math.Pow(2, float64(n-1))))
    fmt.Println(uint64(1) << uint(n-1))
}
```

The output demonstrates that the two methods are different:

```
9223372036854775808
0
```

Comment: While I agree with your answer, I was surprised by the output : why is the printed result `2^63` ? [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wA2Uei7RKV4)

Comment: @LeGEC from the language spec: "In all non-constant conversions involving floating-point or complex values, if the result type cannot represent the value the conversion succeeds but the result value is implementation-dependent."

Comment: ok, there is a rounding effect : on my laptop (amd64), starting from `0xfffffffffffffc00`, `uint64` values get rounded *up* when cast to `float64`. The undefined behavior gives the surprising result that afterwards, values are `2<<63` instead of `max_uint64`. [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YFHvUZwM5vg). Well, although it is a corner case, it's best to know where that one lies :)

Answer (score 6):

[`math.Pow()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Pow) is implemented to operate on `float64` numbers. Bit shifting to calculate powers of 2 can only be applied on integers, and only on a tiny subset where the result fits into `int64` (or `uint64`).

If you have such special case, you're more than welcome to use bit shifting.

Any other case where the result is bigger than `math.MaxInt64` or where the base is not `2` (or a power of `2`) requires floating point arithmetic.

Also note that even if detection of the above possible tiny subset would be implemented, the result is in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format, which also would have to be converted to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format because the return value of `math.Pow()` is `float64` (although these numbers could be cached), which again you'd most likely convert back to `int64`.

Again: if you need performance, use explicit bit shifting.

Answer (score 3):

Because such optimization was never implemented.

The go compiler aims to have fast compile time. Thus, some optimizations are decided to be not worth it. This saves compilation time at the expense of some run-time.

Comment: This is an implementation detail of `math.Pow`, not a compiler optimization.